# Change image in UITableViewCell when selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to change the image in a custom `UITableViewCell`, depending on whether it is selected or not. 
So, when user selects a row, the image in two rows has to be changed (both the current selected and the one to be selected).
Calling `reloadData`, or `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` from `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` doesn't work because it deselects the current selected row, which I don't want to happen.
Calling `reloadData` from `willDeselectRowAtIndexPath` and `willSelectRowAtIndexPath` also causes the same problem. 
Anyone know a solution for this?

Comment: Can you please show me your coding?

Comment: It's ok. I figured out a solution ;)

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: I just set the image in the  setSelected method from my subclassed UITableViewCell class

Comment: Oh.Now does it work fine?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try just programmatically selecting the row in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` based on a stored property indicating the selected row?

I would an approach where you still use `reloadData`, or `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` from `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` but first save the selected row in a property so that you can manually set it as selected when the cell is redrawn.

For example:

```
var selectedRow:NSIndexPath? = nil

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    selectedRow = indexPath
    tableView.reloadData() // or reload a specific row
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TableViewCellReuseIdentifier")
    if (indexPath == selectedRow) {
        cell!.selected = true
    } else {
        cell!.selected = false
    }
}
```